# Unknown Error in Layouts Converting from Android to Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

EDIT: TLTR; This was a long and hard road. Turns out Visual Studio / Xamarin / Android / SOMETHING.. didn't like that I moved the downloaded .xml files into my drawable folder, and just renamed them to .axml so creating new .axml files and pasting the .xml layouts into there seems to have fixed it all.

.....

I think I have an issue in my layouts. The project won't build, but no errors are shown.

What I have noticed is that.. if I delete three blocks of code references my axml and layout ids, the project builds (see comments in first code section below).. also if I grab random axml and layout ids from my project (and not the ones I just imported from the online example) it also builds.

I think the issue might be:

- one of the @dimens, @colors, etc is breaking my layouts, but I tried deleting them all from the .axml files with no luck.
- my layout might be missing some code of declaration in the first Layout object aka RelativeLayout xmlns:android=
- something I'm not catching is different in layouts in regular Android versus Xamarin android

NOTE:

- All three blocks of code MUST be deleted / replaced
- I have restarted my computer, restarted VS, deleted by obj/bin folders, etc.

I am recreating this project but with Xamarin Android C#: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

I have the following code in my Activity OnCreate function: (NOTE that i point out which three blocks of code could be deleted in order for the build to work correctly)

```
class StartUpDialogs : Activity
{
    ...

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 21)
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)(SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable | SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen);
        }

        //REMOVING THE FOLLOWING THREE CODE BLOCKS ALLOWS IT TO BUILD
        // Also replacing with Ids and Layouts not from this example work too
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_welcome);

            viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.view_pager);
            dotsLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutDots);
            btnSkip = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_skip);
            btnNext = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_next);


            // layouts of all welcome sliders
            // add few more layouts if you want
            layouts = new int[]{
                Resource.Layout.welcome_slide1,
                Resource.Layout.welcome_slide2,
                Resource.Layout.welcome_slide3,
                Resource.Layout.welcome_slide4};
        }

        myViewPagerAdapter = new StartUpDialogAdapter(this, layouts);
        viewPager.Adapter = (myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.PageSelected += OnPageChange;

        btnSkip.Click += OnSkip;

        btnNext.Click += GoNext;

    }

    ...

}
```

Here are the layout files:

activity_welcome.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_welcome">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dots_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dots_margin_bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:layout_above="@id/layoutDots"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

welcome_slide1.axml (2 - 4 are identical except with numbers switched out for 2, 3, 4)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_screen1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/img_width_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/img_width_height"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_food" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/slide_1_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/slide_1_desc"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Resource files in case its them: (I had to move string-array into my strings.xml in order for them to be registered in my OnCreate function as the code owners project had it in colors.xml)

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <!-- Screens background color-->
    <color name="bg_screen1">#f64c73</color>
    <color name="bg_screen2">#20d2bb</color>
    <color name="bg_screen3">#3395ff</color>
    <color name="bg_screen4">#c873f4</color>

    <!-- dots inactive colors -->
    <color name="dot_dark_screen1">#d1395c</color>
    <color name="dot_dark_screen2">#14a895</color>
    <color name="dot_dark_screen3">#2278d4</color>
    <color name="dot_dark_screen4">#a854d4</color>

    <!-- dots active colors -->
    <color name="dot_light_screen1">#f98da5</color>
    <color name="dot_light_screen2">#8cf9eb</color>
    <color name="dot_light_screen3">#93c6fd</color>
    <color name="dot_light_screen4">#e4b5fc</color>


</resources>
```

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dots_height">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dots_margin_bottom">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="img_width_height">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="slide_title">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="slide_desc">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="desc_padding">40dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">XXX</string>
  <string name="user_spinner_prompt">Select Account</string>
  <string name="app_name">Intro Slider</string>
  <string name="title_activity_welcome">Home Screen</string>
  <string name="next">NEXT</string>
  <string name="skip">SKIP</string>
  <string name="start">GOT IT</string>
  <string name="slide_1_title">Hello Food!</string>
  <string name="slide_1_desc">The easiest way to order food from your favourite restaurant!</string>
  <string name="slide_2_title">Movie Tickets</string>
  <string name="slide_2_desc">Book movie tickets for your family and friends!</string>
  <string name="slide_3_title">Great Discounts</string>
  <string name="slide_3_desc">Best discounts on every single service we offer!</string>
  <string name="slide_4_title">World Travel</string>
  <string name="slide_4_desc">Book tickets of any transportation and travel the world!</string>
  <string name="play_again_desc">To see the welcome slider again, goto Settings -> apps -> welcome slider -> clear data</string>
  <string name="play_again">Play Again</string>

  <string-array name="array_dot_active">
    <item>@color/dot_light_screen1</item>
    <item>@color/dot_light_screen2</item>
    <item>@color/dot_light_screen3</item>
    <item>@color/dot_light_screen4</item>
  </string-array>

  <string-array name="array_dot_inactive">
    <item>@color/dot_dark_screen1</item>
    <item>@color/dot_dark_screen2</item>
    <item>@color/dot_dark_screen3</item>
    <item>@color/dot_dark_screen4</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check the axml which you copy from Java Project,set their **BuildAction** to **AndroidResource** like this:

[image]